# Homepage with "sub" Views based on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Views:

Project\Views\Home\Index.cshtml

Project\Areas\User\View\Dashboard\Supervisor.cshtml

Project\Areas\User\View\Dashboard\Worker.cshtml

Controllers:

Project\Controller\HomeController.cs

When the index page loads, I want to call an action from the HomeContoller that would detect the user's role and deliver the corresponding view inside of the index page.

Index.cshtml has this general design:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="everybodySees">
        <!-- some interesting stuff-->
    </div>
    <div id="target">
        <!-- some stuff based on user roles -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult UserDashboard([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            ViewResult view;

            var emp = CommonInterfaces.Globals.UserDataSource.GetCurrentUser().GetRole();

            else if (emp == CommonInterfaces.Globals.Roles.Supervisor)
            {
                view = View("../Dashboard/Supervisor");
            }
            else 
            {
                view = View("../Dashboard/Worker");
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Supervisor.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.Users.DashboardEmployeeWorkloadInfo

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyApp.Users.DashboardUnitWorkloadInfo>().Name("TestChart")
        .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("TestChart", "Dashboard")))
        .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom))
        .Series(series => 
                {
                    series.Column(model => model.EmpName).Name("Workers in my Unit");
                })
                .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                    .MajorUnit(1)
                    .Line(line => line.Visible(false)))
            )
    </div>
</div>
```

Worker.cshtml

```
<article>
    <p>
       Area is static for now.
    </p>
</article>
```

I've tried using @{Html.RenderAction("UserDashboard", "Home");} within the #target tag in the Index.cshtml page but get "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."

I'm pretty new to mvc and wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this in MVC.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `UserDashboard` method and see which part of your method is crashing.

Comment: @Shyju It was crashing on the `return` statement. Turns out i was referencing the wrong path for the view files. I'm still looking for ways to reference the views through code and not have to use a hard coded path..

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the user's current role into the View Model, then you could very well do this in the Index.cshtml

```
@if(Model.Emp == CommonInterfaces.Globals.Roles.Supervisor)
{
   <div id="target">
    <!-- some stuff based on user roles -->
</div>
}
else {
<div class="everybodySees">
    <!-- some interesting stuff-->
</div>

}
```

This is assuming, the view portion is exclusive, i.e. user will see either of the views. If the idea is that user should see first the common things and then only specifics, then you can do something like this as well

```
<div class="everybodySees">
    <!-- some interesting stuff-->
</div>

@if(Model.Emp == CommonInterfaces.Globals.Roles.Supervisor)
{
   <div id="target">
    <!-- some stuff based on user roles -->
</div>
}
```

Also if you are passing down the values to partial views from the div target, then you would also need to carry that into main viewmodel and then pass it down further

Comment: I was trying to avoid putting that much logic in the view. I was hoping to do the role check in the controller so I could keep things segmented. I found my problem though, apparently I was passing the wrong path to the View() method in the controller. I should have been using "~/Areas/User/View/Dashboard/Supervisor.cshtml" . I wish there was a way to reference the view with code instead of a string though. I'm sure there's something out there